# Watch an API Endpoint with Socket.io

Tags: javascript, node.js, sockets, websocket

Im trying to set up web sockets to monitor changes at an API endpoint.

I am able to set up web sockets across my native Node.js server and client.

Server:

```
var app = http.createServer(function(req, res){
    //...
});

var io = require('socket.io').listen(app);

io.on('connection', function(socket) {

    console.log("socket connection OK");

    io.emit('hi', 'hello from server');

});
```

Client:

```
socket.on('hi', function(msg){

    console.log(msg);
});
```

But I would like to listen for changes to an API endpoint from my node.js server.

In pseudocode:

My node.js server

```
var app = http.createServer(function(req, res){
    //...
});

var io = require('socket.io').listen("http://SOME-API-ENDPOINT.com/data");

io.on('connection', function(socket) {

    console.log("socket connection OK");

});

socket.on('hi', function(msg){

    console.log("the endpoint changed!!");
    // DO STUFF

});
```

The Client would not be involved in this example - I would just do stuff on the back end.

Q1) Is this even possible with sockets.io / what web sockets are used for or am I missing the point?

Q2) If not websockets, what type of toolset is appropriate for the problem described above?

Comment: Have you found out the solution? I have the same problem